# How to override member variable in derived class?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a base class that I plan to extend for several different sequences, and each sequence needs to have its own seq_cfg object. I also want the base class to have a base seq_cfg object that the other derived classes' seq_cfg's can extend from. So I want to implement something like below:

```
virtual class base_seq_cfg extends uvm_object;
    my_sequencer_c sqr;
endclass

virtual class base_seq extends uvm_object;
    base_seq_cfg cfg;
    task send_item();
        //assume this seq is defined somewhere else
        basic_seq_c basic_seq;
        basic_seq.start(cfg.sqr, this);
    endtask
endclass

class test_seq1_cfg extends base_seq_cfg;
     int iterations;
endclass

class test_seq1 extends base_seq;
    test_seq1_cfg cfg; //I don't think I can override the 'cfg' object handle like this
    task body();
        for (int i = 0; i < cfg.iterations; ++i) begin
            send_item();
        end
    endtask
endclass
```

So I want to be able to define several different sequences like `test_seq1` that extend from `base_seq` and use it's common functions/tasks like `send_item`. But I also want the sequences that extend from `base_seq` to have their own seq_cfg's that also extend from `base_seq_cfg`. And I would still like for the base_seq to be able to use the `cfg` object to access the sequencer. However if I try to override the `cfg` object definition in the derived class, I get a compiler error. Is there another way I can do this that will compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to test_seq1_cfg before using it. below code solves issue in your code.

```
class test_seq1 extends base_seq;
    
    task body();
        test_seq1_cfg cfg_n;
        $cast(cfg_n,cfg); // cast parent class handle to child class
        for (int i = 0; i < cfg_n.iterations; ++i) begin
            send_item();
        end
    endtask
endclass
```

Note : Here I assume that you have assigned test_seq1_cfg object to cfg in your test as shown below.

```
class test1 extends uvm_test;

  `uvm_component_utils(test1) 
  
  test_seq1  seq;
  test_seq1_cfg cfg1;

  function new(string name = "test1",uvm_component parent=null);
    super.new(name,parent);
    cfg1 = new();
    cfg1.iterations=10;
  endfunction : new

  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    seq = test_seq1::type_id::create("seq");
    seq.cfg=cfg1; // assign child class handle to parent.
  endfunction : build_phase

endclass : test
```